# Best method to scale HTML elements

Tags: html, css, svg, widget, scale

Im looking for some options regarding scaling some HTML elements for use on a large screen (like a kiosk). I'm currently using CSS3 scale() to get a relatively cross-browser scale (thanks to cssplease), but seeing if anyone else has any better suggestion.

Primarily, I'm looking at rendering widgets (HTML, js, and images) on a large scale (from 400x200px to 800x500 for example). While I could rewrite each widget for a larger scale, I thought I'd check my options.

Is there something that SVG can do, or canvas? CSS3 scale() is okay, but images need to be replaced with high-res versions. Text spacing seems to also be slightly off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 Transforms are still the best option for what I want, especially for browser performance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Understood you right, but if you need your website, images, videos etc to look good on any screen (with any resolution) you could try to go for responsive design. You have option of using css media queries to adjust website for different screen resolutions, it will also maintain original image quality etc.

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps 
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/

I found them very help full and once you get into it you would easily build scalable websites ;))

Comment: While on the right track (media queries is a good idea), lts a little more involved than using a responsive design. I actually need to scale something smal by 200% so its visible on a 1080p led screen. A responsive design just allows you to adjust the layout of the page element, not the size. Good resources though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may be an extensive retrofit but you might be able to define your elements' dimensions using ems then use media queries to increase the base font size for different screen sizes. So if your base font size is 16px, you main column might be 47em, sidebar 12em, for an approximate site width of 1000px. You could then use media queries to detect a larger browser and all you need to do is increase the base font size to 20px and viola your site is now 25% bigger.

Comment: I think that will fix the font spacing issues I'm having, by switching to either ems or percentages (using pixels).